# Помогите с задачей, нужно вместо круглых скобок вводимых с клавиатуры поставить квадратные скобки а в них, позицию этих скобок

Tags: java

Помогите с задачей, нужно вместо круглых скобок вводимых с клавиатуры поставить квадратные скобки а в них, позицию этих скобок ,по типу если я введу "helloy()world()helloy()world"
и оно должно выводить "helloy[1]world[2]helloy[3]world
Пока вставляется только индекс первой скобки

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static StringBuilder del(StringBuilder s1) {
        int start = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        int a = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s1.length() - 1; j++)
            {
                a++;
                String aString = Integer.toString(a);
                if (s1.charAt(j) == '('  && flag) {
                    start = j;
                    flag = false;
                }
                if (s1.charAt(j) == ')'  && !flag) {
                    flag = true;
                    s1.replace(start, j+1 ,"["+aString+"]");
                }
            }
        }
        return s1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите строку: ");
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Преобразованная строка: " + del(s1));


    }
}
```

Comment: как предлагается поступать вот с таким примером? какой должен быть вывод? ```hell(o(w)o)r)ld)it's()))(alive```

Comment: hell[1]o)r)ld)its[2]))(alive что то типо такого

Comment: Но это не важно сколько и в каком порядке , скобки важен вопрос, как сделать чтоб позиция вставлялась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static StringBuilder del(StringBuilder s1) {
    int start = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s1.length() - 1; j++)
        {
            if (s1.charAt(j) == '('  && flag) {
                start = j;
                flag = false;
            }
            if (s1.charAt(j) == ')'  && !flag) {
                flag = true;
                String aString = Integer.toString(a);
                s1.replace(start, j+1 ,"["+aString+"]");
                a++;
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Обновите, я слегка поправил код и вернул второй цикл, понял что без него будет небольшая ошибка с таким подходом к замене символов, но вложенный цикл вот так как у вас - плохая идея, лучше переделать на while или на сборку новой строки из частей старой...

Comment: Понял , спасибо еще раз